# Cannot import Xgboost package in PyCharm (Jupyter) after installation

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, python-import, xgboost

I am using Pycharm (2017.3.5) as my IDE for Python (3.6) and I integrated Jupyter notebook for development.

Untill now, I had no problems with instaling new packages and I did it using Pycharm.

Today I am struggling with machine learning library called xgboost.

Firstly, the installation error was that I need to update pip. I did it form ver 9.7 to 10.1. And then the installation succeded as follows:

[image: Step1]

[image: Step2]

[image: Step3]

[image: why?]

Even after "Package installed succesfully" it is not listed above in packages list (I also tried to reopen pycharm)

---

When scanning my computer I found that xgboost has been downloaded to anaconda  folder:
    C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\xgboost

Shouldn't then I be able to import it in pycharm like any other package?

---

I found that simmilar problems had people here:

- [Xgboost work on pycharm but not in Jupyter NoteBook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848254/xgboost-work-on-pycharm-but-not-in-jupyter-notebook) but even when I run pip install xgboost in anaconda terminal window I receive this error:
  [image]
  .

when I run:

```
import os
print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep))
```

result: ['C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\Kaggle'], but this is just the name where I keep my files and codes, I don't want to have packages here. 
Also here was recommended to:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\sifangyou\xgboost\python-package")
import xgboost
```

But I don't which directory should I state in my case.

---

- Another similar question: [Jupyter notebook xgboost import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856105/jupyter-notebook-xgboost-import)

but when I run:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', '<xgboost>'])
```

I have:
[image]

---

My background is in statistics not in computer science therefore I am way above my capabilities and would appriciate some explanation regarding how Anaconda, Pycharm and Python libriaries are connected as I by accident integrated Conda with Pycharm and was able to install libraries like Pandas or Numpy but when I run into troubles with xgboost I have no idea what I am doing and just try random solutions found on internet.

Thanks!